# Turn off name hints for TextInputEditText

Tags: android, textinput

I'm developing an app where the user should enter a list of names. How should I configure my TextInputEditText so it would not suggest my own name all the time?

I have tried `android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords|textNoSuggestions"` but there is still a pop-up bubble where I can select my name. How do I remove the pop-up bubble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue a few weeks ago. What worked for me is the following flag in the editText

```
 android:importantForAutofill="no"
```

[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize?hl=es-419#important)